# Continuous activity

Tags: would-rather

A friend of mine is a newspaper reporter. I want to tell him that I am reading his articles continuously. By this, I mean that I read it in the past, I am reading in the present, and I will read in future too. Is it okay to say:

> I have been reading all you articles in the newspaper.

Or should I put:

> I would read all your articles in the newspaper.

Answer (score 1):

Since the present can be used to state a general habit or practice, we can also use the simple present or the present-continuous:

> I read all your articles.
>
> I'm reading all your articles.

The continuous would be better  than simple present in a letter since we can't tell from *read* whether it is past or present in that sentence if we cannot hear the word spoken ( [red] or [rId] ).

The present is a little firmer than the present perfect continuous **have been reading** with regard to your intention to continue reading them.

You can also say:

> I read every article you write.

That suggests you have been a reader of your friend's articles for quite some time, and intend to  read any article he writes. We know that "read" is present here because "you write" tells us so; "read" could be past only if "write" was "wrote".

Answer (score 0):

I think "I have been reading all your articles." is correct.

---

"I would read all your articles." could be interpreted differently. There I would understand that you **would/would have** read my articles but **don't/didn't** (because of whatever reasons). But since you did read them it should be "have been", it doesn't exactly include the future, but doesn't exclude it.

Comment: By itself, and depending on context, the phrasing "I have been reading all your articles" can suggest that you have, recently, sat down with all the articles and started reading them from start to finish. I think it's a little too specific to get the meaning desired here.